# Joining a Grouped list, together with median values for each grouped record

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb, aggregate-functions, median

I'm trying to join data together, my goal is to have list of sellers, and see next to each seller, the median time it took him to sell his items.

The following query works as expected on a single seller (dan), and returns a value:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(timetook) AS Median
FROM (
  SELECT 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, starttime, endtime) AS timetook,
    @rownum:=@rownum+1 as `row_number`,
    @total_rows:=@rownum
  FROM items, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  WHERE total_price > 100 AND seller_name = "dan"
  ORDER BY timetook ASC
) AS temp
WHERE 
  `row_number` = FLOOR((@total_rows + 1) / 2) OR
  `row_number` = CEIL((@total_rows + 1) / 2)
```

However, when trying to see it as a list of sellers (for testing I test on two sellers only), I get null values for the medians of the sellers.

```
SELECT 
  q1.seller_name, 
  q1.records_found,
  q2.median_timetook
FROM (
  SELECT 
    seller_name,
    COUNT(*) AS records_found
  FROM items 
  WHERE 
    total_price > 100 AND 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, starttime, endtime) < 60 
  GROUP BY seller_name 
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
) AS q1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    seller_name,
    AVG(timetook) AS median_timetook
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      seller_name,
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, starttime, endtime) AS timetook,
      @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS row_number,
      @total_rows:=@rownum
    FROM 
      items, 
      (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
    ORDER BY 
      timetook ASC
  ) AS temp
  WHERE 
    row_number = FLOOR((@total_rows + 1) / 2) OR
    row_number = CEIL((@total_rows + 1) / 2)
  GROUP BY 
    seller_name
) AS q2 ON q1.seller_name = q2.seller_name
WHERE
  q1.seller_name IN ('ron', 'dan') 
GROUP BY
  q1.seller_name
ORDER BY 
  q1.records_found DESC
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: is this MySQL?

Comment: yeah mysql maridb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using window functions rather than user variables; the latter is deprecated, and planned for removal in a future MySQL version. Window functions are much more easy to use, especially when it comes to managing partitions.

Here is one way to compute the median per seller:

```
select seller_name, avg(duration) as median_duration
from (
    select i.*,
        row_number() over(partition by seller_name order by duration) rn,
        count(*) over(partition by seller_name) cnt
    from (
        select i.*, 
            timestampdiff(minute, starttime, endtime)) duration 
        from items i
    ) i
) i
where rn in ( floor((cnt + 1) / 2), floor( (cnt + 2) / 2) )
group by seller_name
```

Comment: Just to add a bit: specifically *setting* user variables *in a select* is deprecated, and afaik only in mysql, not mariadb.

Comment: good answer for mysql; for mariadb there is a median function, so this is way overkill

Answer (score 0):

In mariadb, there is a median function (though unfortunately only as a window function), so you can do:

```
select distinct seller_name, median(timestampdiff(minute, starttime, endtime)) over (partition by seller_name) timetook
from items
where total_price > 100
order by timetook
```